# Does openMRS have open data?

Tags: medical

Does the [Open Medical Records System](http://openmrs.org/) expose patients medical records for public data mining or research?

Comment: Response from official openMRS Twitter account: https://twitter.com/OpenMRS/status/841917091011784706

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I cannot at present find a citation to support this assertion (I'm on mobile and their site isn't mobile-friendly), I am almost positive from having worked with Open MRS once that OpenMRS does not provide any open data from the organizations running their open-source health record system.

For one, this would be a violation of the open-source ToS, which explicitly state that Open MRS does not record any of the confidential patient data itself.

Second, just to clarify, the 'Open' part of their namesake refers more to the fact that the software itself is open for use as a platform. Not to open as in open data.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, OpenMRS is an electronic medical record platform. It absolutely captures confidential information for clinician use. There is a big difference between OpenMRS as an EMR and OpenMRS as a data repository. As mentioned above, Open refers to the software code used to modify and enhance the application and in no way represents access to patient data. Presumably, if someone wanted to use OpenMRS for secondary use (population health, analytics, etc.), the data would be de-identified so that no confidential information could be seen or data ascribed to a particular person.